# Haskell aeson package basic usage

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

Working my way through Haskell and I'm trying to learn how to serialized to/from JSON.

I'm using aeson-0.8.0.2 & I'm stuck at basic decoding. Here's what I have:

file playground/aeson.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text
import Data.Aeson

data Person = Person
    { name :: Text
    , age  :: Int
    } deriving Show


instance FromJSON Person where
    parseJSON (Object v) = Person <$>
                           v .: "name" <*>
                           v .: "age"

    parseJSON _          = mzero


main = do
    let a = decode "{\"name\":\"Joe\",\"age\":12}" :: Maybe Person
    print "aa"
```

ghc --make playground/aeson.hs yields:

> [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( playground/aeson.hs,
>   playground/aeson.o )
>
> playground/aeson.hs:13:35: Not in scope: `'
>
> playground/aeson.hs:14:40: Not in scope: `<*>'
>
> playground/aeson.hs:17:28: Not in scope: `mzero'

1. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
2. Why is OverloadedString needed here?
3. Also, I have no idea what `<$>`, `<*>`, or `mzero` are supposed to mean; I'd appreciate tips on where I can read about any of these.

Comment: Do you know about hoogle? If not then Google for hoogle.

Comment: Go and hit https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/ to find out about `<$>` and friends.

Comment: Thanks, looking through hoogle I deduced I lacked some `import`s. Now it seems to compile.

Comment: The `<$>` and `<*>` are part of a Haskell thing called _applicative style_.  There's a good explanation on [learnyouahaskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `Control.Applicative` and `Control.Monad` to get `<$>`, `<*>` and `mzero`.  `<$>` just an infix operator for `fmap`, and `<*>` is the `Applicative` operator, you can think of it as a more generalized form of `fmap` for now.  `mzero` is defined for the `MonadPlus` class, which is a class representing that a `Monad` has the operation

```
mplus :: m a -> m a -> m a
```

And a "monadic zero" element called `mzero`.  The simplest example is for lists:

```
> mzero :: [Int]
[]
> [1, 2, 3] `mplus` [4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Here `mzero` is being used to represent a failure to parse.  For looking up symbols in the future, I recommend using [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) or [FP Complete's version](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle).  Once you find the symbol, read the documentation, the source, and look around for examples of its use on the internet.  You'll learn a lot by looking for it yourself, although it'll take you a little while to get used to this kind of research.

The `OverloadedStrings` extension is needed here because the `Aeson` library works with the `Text` type from `Data.Text` instead of the built-in `String` type.  This extension lets you use string literals as `Text` instead of `String`, just as the numeric literal `0` can be an `Int`, `Integer`, `Float`, `Double`, `Complex` and other types.  `OverloadedStrings` makes string literals have type `Text.String.IsString s => s` instead of just `String`, so it makes it easy to use alternate string-y types.

Answer (score 0):

For `<$>` you need to import `Control.Applicative` and for `mzero` you need to import `Control.Monad`.

You can determine this by using the web-based version of hoogle (http://www.haskell.org/hoogle) or the command line version:

```
$ hoogle '<$>'
$ hoogle mzero
```